# How to change lightbox2 arrows position of this plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox2

Im working with Lightbox2 plugin http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/. I need:

1. always show nav arrows
2. arrows show on left and right side of browser, like float: left, right (not on image)
3. close button show on browser top right position

Please help me, how to do that options. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To always show the nav arrows, you will have to change their `opacity` to 1 (it is 0 by default).

Here:

```css
.lb-nav a.lb-prev, .lb-nav a.lb-next {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Then to keep them on the side of the browser window you can change change the `position` property to `fixed` and then change the individual arrows accordingly, like this:

```css
.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

and finally you can move the entire bottom block by messing around with the positioning like this:

```css
.lb-dataContainer {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Keep in mind, these solutions are far from perfect. This is a quick and dirty way to move elements around.

Comment: all its fine and works but thirdly, i need change position only close button (not all container with title) and close button must be on browser right top like arrows on browser left/right. How to do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Due to the structure, it would work better to move the entire container up. If you were to move just the closing button, you would lose the responsive holding container that it's in. By doing this, the close button will be in a static position, no matter what size the image in the lightbox grows to: i.e. the button would sometimes be far away from the image, and other times it would be right on top of it.